# Reverse String Word by Word in Java

Tags: java, string

I have the following code to reverse a string word by word, I have a question though, first could anyone point at how to make it better code? and second, how can I remove the space that I end up with at the beginning of the new string.

```
String str = "hello brave new world";
tStr.reverseWordByWord(str)

public String reverseWordByWord(String str){
        int strLeng = str.length()-1;
        String reverse = "", temp = "";

        for(int i = 0; i <= strLeng; i++){
            temp += str.charAt(i);
            if((str.charAt(i) == ' ') || (i == strLeng)){
                for(int j = temp.length()-1; j >= 0; j--){
                    reverse += temp.charAt(j);
                    if((j == 0) && (i != strLeng))
                        reverse += " ";
                }
                temp = "";
            }
        }

        return reverse;
    }
```

the phrase at the moment becomes:

> olleh  evarb  wen dlrow

notice the space at the beginning of the new string.

Comment: Your code will work by just editing the for loops like `if((str.charAt(i) == ' ') || (i == strLeng)){
              if(i==strLeng){
               temp+=" ";
              }
                 for(int j = temp.length()-2; j >= 0; j--){`  But if you are looking for a better coding, Dawood has got the simplest and inbuilt way to do it.

Comment: What is "better code"?  Faster?  More concise?  More "elegant" or "clever"?  Easier to read maintain?  This clearly calls for opinion-based answers.

Answer (score 7):

Not using the split function the code would look like:

```
public static void reverseSentance(String str) {
    StringBuilder revStr = new StringBuilder("");
    int end = str.length(); // substring takes the end index -1
    int counter = str.length()-1;
    for (int i = str.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) {     
        if (str.charAt(i) == ' ' || i == 0) {
            if (i != 0) {
                revStr.append(str.substring(i+1, end));
                revStr.append(" ");
            }
            else {
                revStr.append(str.substring(i,end));
            }
            end = counter;
        }
        counter--;
    }
    System.out.println(revStr);
}
```

Comment: You can remove the `counter` variable and replace it with `i`, and remove the `counter--` line.

Answer (score 7):

If str = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog!" it will return it like "dog! lazy the over jumped fox brown quick The" ...

```
  private static String Reverse(String str) {
      char charArray[] = str.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i <str.length(); i++){
        if(charArray[i] == ' ')
        return Reverse(str.substring(i + 1)) + str.substring(0, i) + " ";
    }

    return str + " ";
}
```

Comment: If you are using a charArray then why not go for a string array would be much easy.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you could do it:

```
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input, " ");
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        StringBuilder thisToken = new StringBuilder(st.nextToken());
        result.append(thisToken.reverse() + " ");
    }
    String resultString = result.toString();
```

Comment: This isn't quite right. It makes the assumption that all words in the sentence(s) are necessarily delimited by spaces. What happens when punctuation marks are encountered?

Comment: Good point.. I just posted a quick solution based on OP's code since he is also delimiting on spaces (line 10: `if (str.charAt(i) == ' ')`). You're right in that for a comprehensive solution, one would need to add other delimiters too.

Answer (score 2):

My approach using StringUtils. In a unit test.

```
@Test
public void testReversesWordsAndThenAllCharacters(){
    String sentence = "hello brave new world";
    String reversedWords = StringUtils.reverseDelimited(sentence, ' ');
    String reversedCharacters = StringUtils.reverse(reversedWords);
    assertEquals("olleh evarb wen dlrow", reversedCharacters);
}
```

If you static import StringUtils, this could be inlined to:

```
reverse(reverseDelimited("hello brave new world", ' '))
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would do is to separate code reversing the words form code reversing each word individually. This inner loop:

```
for(int j = temp.length()-1; j >= 0; j--)
{
    reverse += temp.charAt(j);
    if((j == 0) && (i != strLeng))
        reverse += " ";
}
```

Would be a function/method call.

Also, to make your code more performant, instead of concatenating strings with the `+` operator, I would use a string buffer class. Such as [`StringBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) or [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Comment: `StringBuilder` comes with a built-in `reverse()` method, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should decouple it in three functions. The first breaking the big string in a  list of strings using the space as delimiter, the second reversing one string without spaces, and the last concatenating strings.

When you do that it will be easier to locate what cause the space to appears. You can already see that in the current code but I am not going to tell you :D.

Answer (score 1):

How about using something like this?

```
String string="yourWord";
String reverse = new StringBuffer(string).reverse().toString();
```

Comment: I would use this except I'm practicing for interviews and they don't let me use either this or tokenizer

Comment: @LuisArmando OK then, it's answer to the `first could anyone point at how to make it better code?` part.

Comment: True, thanks for pointing that out as I would've never done it this way anyway (lack of practice)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#reverseDelimited%28java.lang.String,%20char%29)

```
return StringUtils.reverseDelimitedString(str, " ");
```

Comment: This won't work. "reverseDelimitedString" will return: "world new brave hello" which is not what the user wants.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It takes into account punctuations and whitespace characters of any kind.

```
public String reverseWordByWord(String inputStr)
{
    BreakIterator wordIterator = BreakIterator.getWordInstance();
    wordIterator.setText(inputStr);
    int start = wordIterator.first();
    StringBuilder tempBuilder;
    StringBuilder outBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int end = wordIterator.next(); end != BreakIterator.DONE; start = end, end = wordIterator.next())
    {
        tempBuilder = new StringBuilder(inputStr.substring(start, end));
        outBuilder.append(tempBuilder.reverse());
    }
    return outBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: It's even locale agnostic. :) The sentence "hello brave new world. I am here to stay.", becomes "olleh evarb wen dlrow. I ma ereh ot yats."

Answer (score 1):

```
public class StringReversers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = new String(revStr("hello brave new world"));
        String st = new String(revWords("hello brave new world"));
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(st);
    }

    public static String revStr(String s){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i=s.length()-1; i>=0;i--){
            sb.append(s.charAt(i));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static String revWords(String str) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String revd = revStr(str);
        for (String s : revd.split(" ")){
            sb.append(revStr(s));
            sb.append(" ");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void reverseByWord(String s) {

        StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(s);

        System.out.println(token.countTokens());
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
        while (token.hasMoreElements()) {
            stack.push(token.nextElement().toString());
        }

        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(stack.pop());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution without using split method

```
    public static String reverseWordsWithoutSplit(String str) {
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    int length = str.length();
    while(length >0) {
        int wordstart = length -1;
        while(wordstart >0 && str.charAt(wordstart) != ' '){
            wordstart--;
        }
        buffer.append(str.substring(wordstart==0?wordstart:wordstart+1, length));
        if(wordstart>0)
            buffer.append(" ");
        length = wordstart;
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another Solution. This solution is in-place.

Reverse words in a string (words are separated by one or more spaces), spaces can precede word(s) i.e space at begin of sentence, end etc... Solve it in-place.

```
public class ReverseWordsInString {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    char[] sentence = "  Hi my name is person!".toCharArray();
    System.out.println(ReverseSentence(sentence));  

}
private static char[] ReverseSentence(char[] sentence)
{
    //Given: "Hi my name is person!"
    //produce: "iH ym eman si !nosrep"
    //the obvious naive solution: utilize stringtokenize to separate each word into its own array. reverse each word and insert space between each array print
    //better solution: drop stringtokenize and use a counter to count how many characters processed before space was hit. 
    //                 once space hit, then jump back swap characters between counter-1 and start position. O(1) Space

    if(sentence == null) return null;
    if(sentence.length == 1) return sentence;       

    int startPosition=0;
    int counter = 0;
    int sentenceLength = sentence.length-1;

    //Solution handles any amount of spaces before, between words etc...    

    while(counter <= sentenceLength)
    {
        if(sentence[counter] == ' ' && startPosition != -1 || sentenceLength == counter) //Have passed over a word so upon encountering a space or end of string reverse word
        {
            //swap from startPos to counter - 1
            //set start position to -1 and increment counter
            int begin = startPosition;

            int end;
            if(sentenceLength == counter)
            {
                end = counter;
            }
            else                
                end = counter -1;
            char tmp;

        //Reverse characters
            while(end >= begin){

                tmp = sentence[begin];
                sentence[begin] = sentence[end];
                sentence[end] = tmp;

                end--; begin++;

            }               

            startPosition = -1; //flag used to indicate we have no encountered a character of a string


        }

        else if(sentence[counter] !=' ' && startPosition == -1) //first time you encounter a letter in a word set the start position
        {
            startPosition = counter;
        }

        counter++;  
    }

    return sentence;        
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Here's one thread also discussing this problem. I think one answer using split with regex is very clever.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/43838/reverse-a-string-word-by-word

```java
public String reverseWordByWord(String s) {
  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
  String[] words = sentence.split("\\s+");      
  for (int i = words.length - 1 ; 0 <= i; i--) {
    result.append(words[i]).append(' ');
  }
  return result.toString().trim();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your removal of the starting space character is easy, just

```
return reverse.trim();
```

`String.trim()` returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted (as copied from the Javadoc documentation).

For your overall problem, I made this sample up:

```
String job = "This is a job interview question!";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(job);
String[] words = job.split(" ");
int i = 0;
for (String word : words) {
    words[i] = (new StringBuilder(word)).reverse().toString();
    i++;
}

System.out.println("job = " + job);
System.out.print("rev = ");
for (String word: words) {
    sb.append(new StringBuilder(word).toString());
    sb.append(" ");
}

String rev = sb.toString().trim();
System.out.println(rev);
```

and the output is:

```
job = This is a job interview question!
rev = sihT si a boj weivretni !noitseuq
```

If you want to be more inclusive of any white space character, e.g., tab character, line break, form feed, then change the `split()` argument to `split("\\s")` as `\s` is the regex character class which embodies [ \t\r\n\f]. Notice how you must escape the backslash character in your Java string representation of a regular expression (which is what the split method expects).

Answer (score 1):

## how to reverse word in java

```
public class ReverseString {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String reverse = "";
    String original = new String("hidaya");
     
      for ( int i = original.length() - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
         reverse = reverse + original.charAt(i);
 
      System.err.println("Orignal string is: "+original);
      System.out.println("Reverse string is: "+reverse);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a coding technique using the popular `split`() function, which is available in all major languages, the Java `toCharArray`(), good for full control of characters in a string form, and the Java `StringBuilder` class for performance sake (available in C# too).

I think the code is easier to understand when compared to the other posted answers

```
public static String reverseWordByWord(String sentence) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String[] words = sentence.split("\\s+");   // space(s) are the delimiters

    for (String word : words) {
        char[] charArray = word.toCharArray();
        int iEnd = word.length() - 1;

        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = iEnd; i >= 0; i--) {
            temp.append(charArray[ i]);
        }
        result.append(temp);
        result.append(" ");     // separate the words
    }
    return result.toString().trim();    // remove the trailing spaces
}
```

Reminder of the requirements posted by the author.
Sample **input**: "Hello World" 
**Output**: "olleH dlroW"

Answer (score 0):

The following should do it in O(n) without any expensive array copying or re-structuring the character array length. Takes care of multiple preceding, in-between and trailing whitespaces.

```
public class ReverseString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string1 = "hello brave new world";
        String string2 = "hello brave new world ";
        String string3 = " hello brave new world";
        String string4 = " hello  brave          new world ";

        System.out.println(reverseStringWordByWord(string1));
        System.out.println(reverseStringWordByWord(string2));
        System.out.println(reverseStringWordByWord(string3));
        System.out.println(reverseStringWordByWord(string4));
    }

    private static String reverseStringWordByWord(String string) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int length = string.length();
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++) {
            char c = string.charAt(i);
            if(c == ' ') {
                sb.append(c);
            } else {
                int j = i;
                while(j < length && string.charAt(j) != ' ') {
                    j++;
                }
                sb.append(reverseString(string.substring(i, j)));
                i = j-1;
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static String reverseString(String string) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=string.length()-1;i>=0; i--) {
            sb.append(string.charAt(i));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Ops you've a got an extra whitespace at the end=)

Comment: There are split() and reverse functions provided in java, there is no need to invent them again

Comment: @prajeeshkumar Java is used as the language to express what the OP actually asked for. I was trying to answer what the OP asked for and not teach him Java

Comment: OP asked `first could anyone point at how to make it better code?` How does avoiding simpler provided methods help ? OP's original code will work by just adding `if(i==strLeng){
               temp+=" ";
              }
                 for(int j = temp.length()-2; j >= 0; j--){ ` if the question was to get it working in the similar fashion

Comment: @prajeeshkumar what if the language was something else. This question is basically an algorithm for reversing a string. I can see you saying next, why do you need to know how mergesort works when java has `Collections.sort()`. There is no need to re-invent mergesort but there is all the needs there can be to know how it works. That is the essence of this post.

Comment: @prajeeshkumar moreover using string.split() in java uses regex and synchronized methods. using it for small chores can lead to performance trouble for a huge string. a big no-no at least in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String reverseStringWordByWord(String input) {
        StringBuilder returnValue = new StringBuilder();
        int insertIndex = 0;
        for(int i = 0;i < input.length();i++ ) {
            if(input.charAt(i)!=' ') {
                returnValue.insert(insertIndex, currentChar);
            } else {
                insertIndex = i+1;
                returnValue.append(currentChar);
            }

        }

        return returnValue.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to Java myself, and I expect I've been beaten to the punch but I thought I'd give it a go anyway. You could solve the extra whitespace problem by building up the string with the assumption that you will delete the unwanted extra space at the end. If performance is a consideration then you might want to rethink this!

Edit: Note that my solution (now) handles leading and trailing whitespace.

```
public class StringReversal {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "hello brave new world";
    System.out.println("\"" + reverseWordByWord(str) + "\"");
}

public static String reverseWordByWord(String str) {
    String reverse = "";
    boolean first = true;
    for (String s : str.split(" ")) {
        if (first) {
            first = false;
        } else {
            reverse += " ";
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            sb.append(s.charAt(i));
        }
        reverse += sb.toString();
    }
    while (reverse.length() < str.length()) {
        reverse += " ";
    }
    return reverse.substring(0, reverse.length());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm assuming that you're learning/practicing java and that there is a high risk of homework question... This means that you'll either love or hate this answer...

If you take a look at the String object source code you'll find something like this inside:

`private final char value[]; //this stores the String's characters`

The first step is to get that *value[]* with:

```
char[] myChars = str.toCharArray();
```

Note the function implementation (from [openjdk-7](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/)), it returns a copy of the array and not the original one because String objects are immutable.

```
public char[] toCharArray() {
    char result[] = new char[count];
    getChars(0, count, result, 0); //Calls System.arraycopy(...)
    return result;
}
```

Now that we have `myChars` we can play around with it and get to the result in linear time O(n)!

```
public static String reverseWordByWord(String str) {
    char[] myChars = str.toCharArray();
    int stringLen = myChars.length;

    int left = 0, right = 0;
    for(int index = 0; index < stringLen; index++) {
        if(chars[index] == ' ') {
            //assign right
            reverse(chars, left, right);
            //update left
        }
    }
    //Don't forget to handle the boundary case (last word in the String)!
}
```

And here is the *reverse* function:

```
private static void reverse(char[] chars, int left, int right) {
    while(left < right) {
        //Would you know how to swap 2 chars without using a "char tmp" variable? ;)
        //Update left and right
    }
}
```

Now just for fun you might want to try to get to the following output instead and maybe you'll get this exact question from some interviewer that ran out of fantasy one day:

`world new brave hello`

Answer (score 0):

Take a String and using `Stack` methods with `StringTokenizer` Object and with its methods we can cut the String into the piece of Words using `delimeter`. By the Stack Natural feature insert `(push)` all the words into the Satck and Remove `(pop)` all the words from Stack. then print of those all.

Here we can take the String s="hello brave new world"

```
import java.util.*;
 public class StringReverse {   
  public static void main(String[] argv) { 
      String s = "hello brave new world";      
      Stack<String> myStack = new Stack<String>();
      StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s); 
        while (st.hasMoreTokens())
           myStack.push((String) st.nextElement());      
           // Print the stack backwards     
           System.out.print('"' + s + '"' + " backwards by word is:\n\t\"");     
         while (!myStack.empty()) {        
           System.out.print(myStack.pop());       
           System.out.print(' ');     
        }     System.out.println('"');
    } 
}
```

If you are using any package with your own then check the [Output of above program](http://javabynataraj.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-reverse-string-sentence-in-java.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
   StringBuilder sb = " This  is cool";
    sb.reverse(); //sb now contains "looc si  sihT "
    System.out.println(sb);
    for(int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++)
    {
        int index = sb.indexOf(" ", i);
       // System.out.println(index);
        if(index > 0)
        {
            sb.replace(i, index, new StringBuilder(sb.substring(i, index)).reverse().toString());
            i = index;
        }
        if(index < 0)

        {
            sb.replace(i, sb.length(), new StringBuilder(sb.substring(i, sb.length())).reverse().toString());
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
   //output "cool is  This "
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  // Create Scanner object
  Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);

  // Take no.of strings that the user wants
  int n=s.nextInt();

  // Create a temp array
  String temps[]=new String[n];

  // Initialize the variable before the user input is stored in it
  String st="";

  // Create a words array
  String words[];

  // Skip first line, if not used user input will be skipped one time 
  s.nextLine();

  // Read the no.of strings that user wish to..
  for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
  {

  System.out.println("String #"+(k+1)+": ");

  // Read line
  st=s.nextLine();

 // Split words with a space, because words has spaces at start, end positions.
 words=st.split(" "); 

 // Initialize temps[k] to avoid null
 temps[k]="";

 // Reverse string now!
 for(int i=words.length-1;i>=0;i--)
 {

 // Put each word in user input string from end to start with a space
 temps[k]+=words[i]+" ";

 }
 }

    // Now print the words!
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {

    // Print the reversed strings, trim them to avoid space at last, see in the reverse logic loop, space is attached at last!
    System.out.println("String #"+(i+1)+": "+temps[i].trim());

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product. I'm editing out the link; you must include the proper disclosure if you edit it back in.

Answer (score 0):

I think my code below is more efficient than any code available here:

```
public static void revWordsInStringCStyle(String str){
    char [] str_ch = str.toCharArray();
    System.out.println(str);
    char temp;
    int len = str_ch.length;
    int left = len-1;

    for(int right =0; right<len/2 ;right++){
        temp = str_ch[left];
        str_ch[left] = str_ch[right];
        str_ch[right] = temp;
        left--;
    }

    for(int i =0; i < len ; i++){
        System.out.print(str_ch[i]);

    }
```

}

Example:  "hello world"

will become : "dlrow olleho"

Answer (score 0):

How about this :

```
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String input ="***NGuyen**Van******A*******";
        String temp = "";
        String result ="";
        for( int i = 0 ; i < input.length() ; i++)
        {
            if(input.charAt(i) != '*')
            {
                temp = temp + input.charAt(i);
            }
            else
            {
                if(!temp.equals(""))
                    result = temp + result;
                result =  input.charAt(i) + result ;
                temp ="";
            }
        }

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
Output: *******A******Van**NGuyen***
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do without split function. Instead using substring and for loop.

```
static String reverseSentenceWithoutSplit(String str){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char [] charArray = str.toCharArray();
    int endindex = charArray.length-1;
    // loop in reverse, char by char
    for(int i=charArray.length-1; i>=0; i--){
        char c = charArray[i];
        if(c==' '){
            sb.append(str.substring(i + 1, endindex+1)); // substring- start index inclusive, end index exclusive
            endindex=i-1;// move to first letter
            sb.append(c); // include the space
        }
        if(i==0){ //grab the last word
            sb.append(str.substring(i, endindex+1));
        }
    }
    if(sb.length()==0){ // handle case where string has no space
        return str;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Input: Behind you is a symbol of oppression
Output: oppression of symbol a is you Behind

Input: ThisIsAllOneWord
Output: ThisIsAllOneWord

Answer (score 0):

```
public String reverseEach(String input)
{
    String[] test = input.split(" ");
    String output="";
    for(String t:test)
    {
        String p ="";
        for(int i=t.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            p=p+t.charAt(i);
        }
        output=output+p+" ";
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: you should use StringBuilder instead of combining strings

Answer (score 0):

```
/* this code uses while loop and the position of spaces come correctly which is 
  a problem if you use for loop */


import java.util.*;
class StrWordRev
{
public void rev(String s)
    {
        for(int i=s.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            System.out.print(s.charAt(i));
        }
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

public void main()
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String s,s1="";
    System.out.println("Enter the string : ");
    s=sc.nextLine();
    int i=0;
    while(i<s.length())
    {
        s1="";
        while(i<s.length() && s.charAt(i)!=' ')
        {
            s1=s1+s.charAt(i);
            i++;
        }
        rev(s1);
        i=i+1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
import java.io.*;

class internal1 {
    public static void main(String s[] {
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(System.in);

        try {
            String a = "";
            String b = "";
            System.out.print("Enter the string::");
            a = dis.readLine();
            System.out.print(a.length());
            System.out.println(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i <= a.length() - 1; i++) {
                if (a.charAt(i) == ' ' || a.charAt(i) == '.') {
                    for (int j = b.length() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                        System.out.print(b.charAt(j));
                    }
                    b = "";
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                b = b + a.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without using string functionalities like reverse, substring, split or tokenizer. My 2 cents

```
public String reverseWordByWord(String strToReverse) {
    StringBuilder tempBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder reversedBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    char[] charArray ;
    for (int i=0; i<=strToReverse.length()-1;i++) {

        if (strToReverse.charAt(i) != ' ') {
            tempBuilder.append(strToReverse.charAt(i)); // dont add if space found
        }

        if (strToReverse.charAt(i) == ' ' || i == strToReverse.length()-1) {

            charArray = new String(tempBuilder).toCharArray(); // convert the temp builder to char array (for reversing)

            for (int j=charArray.length-1; j>=0 ;j--) {
                reversedBuilder.append(charArray[j]);
            }
            if ( i != strToReverse.length()-1) // dont add if it is the last character
                reversedBuilder.append(strToReverse.charAt(i));
            tempBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Word by Word : "+new String(reversedBuilder));

    return new String(reversedBuilder);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class REVERSE
{
    public static void main()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter words: ");
        String word = new String(input.nextLine());
        String reverse[] = word.split(" ");
        String Finalword = " ";
        for(int y = reverse.length-1;y>=0;y--){
            Finalword += reverse[y]+" ";
        }
        System.out.println(Finalword);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's The easiest Way To reverse the strings word by word using `Arraylist` and `Tokenizer()` Which is a Good Choice...Have A look At it:

```
import java.util.*;

class ReverseWords{

  public static void main(String args[]){

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println(" Please Enter The String \n");
      String st=sc.nextLine();

    //Using ArrayList
      ArrayList<String> List =new ArrayList<String>();
      StringTokenizer tokens=new StringTokenizer(st);

        while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()){
            List.add(tokens.nextToken());
        }
    Collections.reverse(List);

    Iterator itr=List.iterator();  
    while(itr.hasNext()){  
       System.out.print(itr.next()+" ");  
    }  

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try it may be help for you

```
class Solution {
    public String reverseWords(String s) {
        String[] arr1=s.split(" ");
        String reverseWorlds="";
        for(int i=0;i<=arr1.length-1;i++) {
            String reverseString="";
            for(int j=arr1[i].length()-1;j>=0;j--) {
                char ch=arr1[i].charAt(j);
                reverseString=reverseString+ch;
            }
            if(i==0) {
                reverseWorlds+=reverseString;
            }else {
                reverseWorlds+=" "+reverseString;
            }
        }
        return reverseWorlds;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Example String Value";
        List<Character> chars = str.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).collect(Collectors.toList());
        chars.add(' ');
        List<String> strs = new ArrayList<>();
        final String[] s = {""};
        chars.forEach(character -> {
            if (character != ' ') {
                s[0] += character.toString();
            } else {
                strs.add(s[0]);
                s[0] = "";
            }
        });
        int size = strs.size();
        while (size > 0) {
            System.out.print(strs.get(size - 1) + " ");
            size--;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ReverseWord {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String reverseString = "How are you";
        String[] splitt = reverseString.split(" ");
        StringBuffer str= new StringBuffer();
        String revStr;
        for (int i = splitt.length - 1; i >= 0;i--) {
            revStr = splitt[i];
            str.append(revStr.toString()).append(" ");
        }
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
public class WordReverse {

static StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the correct Sentence :");
    String str = sc.nextLine().replaceAll("\\s+", " ");         //remove unwanted space using regex

    int lastIndex = 0, i = 0;

    for (char chars : str.toCharArray()) {
        if (chars != ' ') {
            i++;
        } else {
            myReverse(str.substring(lastIndex, i).toCharArray());
            lastIndex = i + 1;
            i++;
        }
    }
    myReverse(str.substring(lastIndex, i).toCharArray());       //reverse the last word

    System.out.println(sb);
}
public static void myReverse(char c[]) {
    for (int i = (c.length - 1) ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        sb.append(c[i]);
    }
    sb.append(" ");
} }
```