# Print Words In String Backwards

Tags: java, string, for-loop

So I'm having a bit of trouble with my Computer Science class. I need to write some code that will take a string and print it backwards in reverse word order. He told me to find an empty space, then print from there and then keep searching....and repeat this until the end of the string. I typed my code out and all it does it print the first word 3 times. I know this will probably seem obvious to you guys.

```
public class Backwords

/* 
 * Gets words from main and prints in reverse order
 */
public static String BackwardsString(String str)
{

    String str1 = (" " + str);
    String answer = (" ");
    int lastpos = str1.length();
    for(int currpos = str.length(); currpos >= 0; currpos--) //shazam
    {
        if (str1.charAt(currpos) == ' ')
        {
            for (int p = currpos+1; p <lastpos; p++) //majicks

            answer = answer + str1.charAt(p);
            lastpos = currpos;
            System.out.println(answer);
        }

    }
    return answer;
}
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    System.out.println("Enter a string : ");
    Scanner firststr = new Scanner(System.in); //gets string input
    String str = firststr.next();
    System.out.println(BackwardsString(str));

}
```

}

Comment: Did you mean something like this?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9105277/reverse-string-word-by-word-in-java

Comment: I tried your code with the String "first second third fourth" and got the output "fourththirdsecondfirst". The only problem is that you're not adding spaces between the reversed words. That said, there are many ways to improve your code, as suggested in other answers.

Comment: How did you get that I'm getting "Enter a string : 
first second third fourth
first
first"

Comment: @Eran How did you get that I'm getting "Enter a string : 
first second third fourt. The output is:
first
first"

Comment: This is an example of where using recursion would be simpler and faster. I mention this because there are few problems where this is the case in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Set answer back to `answer = ""` before the second nested for loop

```
for(int currpos = str.length(); currpos >= 0; currpos--) //shazam
    {
        if (str1.charAt(currpos) == ' ')
        {
            answer = "";
            for (int p = currpos+1; p <lastpos; p++) //majicks

                answer = answer + str1.charAt(p);
            lastpos = currpos;
            System.out.println(answer);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Still getting a repeat of the first word @hyades

Comment: That's because you are printing the return value which is the last value of answer. Hence twice.

Comment: input: hello world output: hello

Comment: I was using the original code with scanner. Maybe I implemented wrong? @hyades Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `StringBuilder` instead of `String` here since there can be lot of `String` concatenation which may create more object in the heap.

Using `StringBuilder` you can do this easy way too.

Eg:

```
public static String BackwardsString(String str) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.append(str);
    return stringBuilder.reverse().toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter a string : ");
    Scanner firststr = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = firststr.next();
    System.out.println(BackwardsString(str));
}
```

Comment: alternatively you could also use StringBuffer which offers the same functionallyity: StringBuffer.reverse() http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#reverse%28%29

Comment: @MartinFrank never use `StringBuffer` over `StringBuiler`. `StringBuffer` is the Thread safer one and considerably slow.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("Enter the string ");
 String str = sc.nextLine();
 String[] strArray = str.split(" ");
 StringBuilder reverseString = new StringBuilder("");
 for (int i = strArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
       reverseString.append(strArray[i]+" ");
 }
 System.out.println("Reverse of string is   :  "+reverseString.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably have an easier time splitting the string:

```
String[] words = str1.split(" ");
```

Then you'd work on each word[i] reversing it, you could break it down to a char array, or use a stringbuilder as others have suggested, up to you on what you think is appropriate for your class.

Comment: We have to only use what he taught us. The point is to use a for loop. I would do that probably normally though right?