# take the first letter of a word the user inputs and add it to the end repeatedly in java

Tags: java

So i'm trying to take the first letter of a word the user inputs and add it to the end of the word (this will be a cipher key) until a message is finished

for example:

cipher key - word

message - please help

the cipher key will be turned into ascii numbers divided by 13 so w,o,r,d will be converted into 119,111,114,100 then into 9,9,9,8

So, my question is how do i turn my code into something that would be able to take the first letter of the user inputed cipher key and add it to the end until the message has ended.

so lets say that the cipher key is word and the message is please help the message has 11 characters so the cipher key should put the first letter to the back ten times
 ex: word, ordw, rdow, dwor, word, ordw, etc,.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class swap {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        System.out.println("Enter the word you want to flip");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = sc.nextLine(); //get input from user

    for (;;) {
        char firstLetter = input.charAt(0); //get the first letter
        input = input.substring(1); //remove the first letter from the input string
        input = input + firstLetter; //add first letter to end of input string
        System.out.println("the word you entered flipped is " + input);
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just as a sidenote, how are you planning to convert it back? It may just be me, but the question doesn't seem clear to me. Are you planning to just move the first `char` to the end once per inputted word (ex. `hello` to `elloh`)? Or are you trying to reverse each word (ex. `hello` to `olleh`)?

Comment: Your sentence "So, my question...ended"  doesn't make sense. Edit to clarify, provide examples.

Comment: If you divide the letters by 13, then you'll only retain the information from A to M. I don't understand the concept here. Unless this has nothing to do with Caesar-cypher. Although I'm not sure what this has to do with cyphers. I'm confused, really.

Comment: the cipher key i used is just an example the user will input their cipher key.  after the cipher key gets converted to ascii numbers and divided by thirteen it will then be integrated into a program that will shift the message, that the user will input, by the divided number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement is strange, as sending the first letter to the end of the word for each letter of the word will give the initial word as end result.

If what you want is simply to reverse a word, then you could use a `StringBuilder` and call the `reverse`  method :

```
StringBuilder hello = new StringBuilder("hello");
hello.reverse();
```

hello would be equals to *olleh* in this example. If you don't want to use StringBuilder and need to write the algorithm as it is homework or w/e, then have a look at this thread :

[Reverse String Word by Word in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9105277/reverse-string-word-by-word-in-java)

**Edit :** To answer your comment, here an example of how you could do it for 10 characters.

```
StringBuilder foo = new StringBuilder("somerandom(actuallynotreallyrandom)characters");
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    foo.append(foo.charAt(0));
    foo.deleteCharAt(0);
}
```

Comment: so i added more info into my question   "so lets say...ten times"

Comment: @RStone any feedback on this ?

Comment: so Jean-François how would i integrate this into my code in order to not have the i < 10 not set to ten but to the number of characters that the user inputs

Comment: @RStone Simply loop over `i < input.length()` instead of `i < 10`

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of the question is correct, for `word` as input and `hello world` as message, we get a list `[ordw, rdwo, dwor, word, ordw, rdwo, dwor, word, ordw, rdwo]` as output.

```
String word = "word";
String message = "hello world";
int numShifts = message.length() - 1;
List<String> newWords = new ArrayList<String>();
int wordLength = word.length();
String tempWord = word;
for (int j = 0; j < numShifts ; j++) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String[] charList = tempWord.split("");
    for (int i = 1; i < charList.length; i++) {
        sb.append(charList[(i % wordLength) + 1]);
    }
    tempWord = sb.toString();
    newWords.add(tempWord);
}
System.out.println(newWords);
```

Comment: Arun A K when i try to use your code in textpad it says it can't find .add when i try to compile the file in line: newWords.add(tempWord);

Comment: You will need to import java.util.ArrayList and java.util.List

Comment: I recommend you to use IDEs like Eclipse

Comment: Ur Welcome @RStone . Hope this guides you through.